# Remove 'image' type data

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I would like to remove or truncate the data in a field of type `image` from `SQL Server` in `SQL`.

The field is non null. I have no problem setting it to a byte of value `0` if possible.

The following is what I have tried:

```
update tblData
set Data = 0
```

This gives the error:

> Operand type clash: int is incompatible with image

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As this is a binary field, you should do:

```
update tblData
set Data = 0x0
```

You can see that it works by running this:

```
insert into tblData values (0x30232)
select DATALENGTH(Data) as Size from tblData
update tblData set Data = 0x0
select DATALENGTH(Data) as Size from tblData
```

It prints out 3 as size first and then 1:

```
(1 row(s) affected)
Size
-----------
3

(1 row(s) affected)

(1 row(s) affected)

Size
-----------
1

(1 row(s) affected)
```